# Why does executing debug in 0.13.7 fail with "Could not find agent library jdwp:transport on the library path"?

Tags: debugging, sbt

After update from `0.13.6` to `0.13.7` I cannot debug with `SBT`.
It is installed using `Homebrew`. I tried to reinstall it, `brew doctor` shows nothing.
I did not change/reinstall `Java` between `SBT` update.

```
lgr$ sbt -v -jvm-debug 5005 "project webapp" run
[process_args] java_version = '1.8.0_25'
# Executing command line:
java
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-agentlib:jdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005
-jar
/usr/local/Cellar/sbt/0.13.7/libexec/sbt-launch.jar
"project webapp"
run

Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library jdwp:transport on the library path, with error: dlopen(libjdwp:transport.dylib, 1): image not found
```

I am unsure whether `SBT` is missing some library, or `brew` formula didn't install properly.
I will be helpful for any idea how to fix it.

Reinstalled `Java`, didn't help.

**Workaround** I downloaded `SBT 0.13.6` and it works without problem, so I start to consider this as a sbt bug. Can anyone help to clarify if it is?

Comment: Had the same problem with sbt 0.13.7 installed using homebrew. But, after updating to the latest on homebrew 0.13.8, the problem is resolved :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To piggyback on Eugene's answer above, since the fix is in a bash script, it is pretty easy to apply the fix from https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/pull/85/files manually. Just edit `bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash` to have this:

```
addJava "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=$1"
```

Instead of this:

```
addJava "-agentlib:jdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=$1"
```

(Mind the `:` not `=` between `jdwp` and `transport`).

Answer (score 2):

> It is installed using Homebrew.

Homebrew install is sanctioned by sbt project as a recommended way to install on Mac, but we (I'm one of the sbt devs) currently don't control it. We do however have the official package [sbt/sbt-launcher-package](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blob/master/src/universal/bin/sbt), and last I checked [Homebrew is also using it](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/commit/c679fbc8acbe7e76ae94b1d270aeefc565f25157).

Looking at [git blame](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/blame/master/src/universal/bin/sbt-launch-lib.bash#L72) of the relevant part of the script, it seems like the debug option was "fixed" in [sbt/sbt-launcher-package#83](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/pull/83):

> In sbt-launch-lib.bash, -Xdebug option is used for debugging. We should use -agentlib option for Java 5+.

Maybe your issue should be tracked as a bug in sbt/sbt-launcher-package.

Comment: Thanks! I downloaded sbt 0.3.7 directly from sbt page and the problem remains, so it might be conencted to sbt-laucher-package.

Comment: Yep, it's releated to this bug https://github.com/sbt/sbt-launcher-package/pull/85 too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was fixed in the 0.13.8 version.

Answer (score 0):

At my case the bash fix didn't help but running from bash as:

```
export SBT_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005" 
sbt
```

helped. It is from [here](http://arussel.blogspot.com/2012/09/using-sbt-in-debug-mode.html).